# How to use at_exit in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, circleci

Cucumber doesn't provide kind of AfterAll hook, so we are using `at_exit`. The drawback of it is it changes the exit code. Given the tests failed, and we do not `exit 1` within the `at_exit` block, then cucumber will proceed to return `exit_code = 0`, thus make checking incorrect (for example on CircleCI).

What should we write in `at_exit` block so cucumber won't exit with success status if test fails?

Comment: Are you sure your `at_exit` hook will exit failed cucumber run with code 0? We have test cases that send an email or write log in the `at_exit` hook and as far as I know, the exit code will be 1 if the test failed. And our Jenkins jobs can detect the failed runs even if we use `at_exit` hook. Could you check your cucumber settings or the command you use to trigger your test? Or maybe you should go create an issue on their git repo

Comment: We fixed the issue by storing the exit code at the beginning of the block and re-exit at the end. This is the nature of at_exit block, not cucumber I think. The only problem with cucumber so far is they don't give an AfterAll hook.